# Asp.Net Core Web API, JWT Still Valid with different Database per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I am using asp.net core with JWT for claim based Authorization, Each request to the API is accompanied with some key which tell me which database name this request is associated with, all databases have the same schema, a user might be in one or many databases.

My use case:

1. Generate a login token by accessing the API through database 1 (the user A exists in database 1).
2. Use the token of the same user to access the API again but this time through database 2, (User A does not exist in Database 2) but he is still able to access the API since his token has the required claim.

this is how i'am changing the connection string per request

```
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
            var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
            if (httpContext != null)
                //options.UseSqlServer("newConStr");
        }
```

How can I make sure the user belongs to the current database, off course without having to write manual checks.

Comment: The database(s) that the user belongs to should be added as claims on your JWT. Then, you can simply only allow a particular connection to be used if the user has that claim.

Comment: @ChrisPratt alright but how should i configure the policy in the start up and on the controllers, since databases are dynamically created and i can not hard code them. any suggestions ?

Comment: Based on my understanding of your situation, I'd say your best bet is a custom policy handler that checks the claim against the registered connection. If it doesn't match, you can return a 401 or 403, depending on how you want to handle it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt in the header of each request the request contains a key that let me identify the target database, i'm using that key to change the connection string for the injected context, how can i benefit of that key to tell if this token was generated from the current database or not ?